# Docker: Build your own image issue

Tags: image, macos, build, docker, boot2docker

I'm discovering docker and I followed the getting started section in the official website.
However I'm getting stuck in the "Build your own image" section [link](http://docs.docker.com/mac/step_four/)
in the step 2 when you are asked to build a new image from a docker file.
I'm working on OSX Yosemite and everything I run is from the Boot2Docker terminal.

Here's the dockerfile from the tutorial:

```
FROM docker/whalesay:latest

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y fortunes

CMD /usr/games/fortunes -a | cowsay
```

I build the image

```
docker build -t docker-whale .
```

apt does its stuff and shows me the following log when installing fortunes

```
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
debconf: (This frontend requires a controlling tty.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin:
```

It happens because the TERM environment variable is not set
so adding the line

```
ENV TERM [term name]
```

solved this, however I still have the dkkg-prconfigure alert.
Anyway all this doesn't break the building process, but when I execute the image

```
docker run docker-whale
```

the whale says nothing instead of saying the output of fortunes (empty field) because the program was not found

```
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/games/fortunes: not found
```

I don't know how to solve it because everything seemed to be fine during the build

```
Selecting previously unselected package fortune-mod.
Preparing to unpack .../fortune-mod_1%3a1.99.1-7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking fortune-mod (1:1.99.1-7) ...
Selecting previously unselected package fortunes-min.
Preparing to unpack .../fortunes-min_1%3a1.99.1-7_all.deb ...
Unpacking fortunes-min (1:1.99.1-7) ...
Selecting previously unselected package fortunes.
Preparing to unpack .../fortunes_1%3a1.99.1-7_all.deb ...
Unpacking fortunes (1:1.99.1-7) ...
Setting up librecode0:amd64 (3.6-21) ...
Setting up fortune-mod (1:1.99.1-7) ...
Setting up fortunes-min (1:1.99.1-7) ...
Setting up fortunes (1:1.99.1-7) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
```

A little hint from anyone who already played a bit with this tutorial would be great.

Comment: See also http://serverfault.com/a/670688/80733

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `dpkg-preconfigure` error messages you could fix with running the following line before you invoke `apt`:

```
RUN echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections
```

The *not found* issue is caused by a typo. Simply replace

```
CMD /usr/games/fortunes -a | cowsay
```

by:

```
CMD /usr/games/fortune -a | cowsay
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm so ashamed XD, I hate typo issues.

Comment: That's a miss in their documentation. Any idea how to request an update to their docs? Are they on GitHub anywhere?

Comment: You can find the documentation [here](https://github.com/docker/tutorials). They corrected it already in their master branch.

Comment: I was unable to see the `/bin/sh: 1: /usr/games/fortunes: not found` error even after I invoked with `docker run --log-driver=json-file ...` and then `docker ps -a` to get the container ID, and then `docker logs 6b362a9f73eb`.  By the way, why isn't there a `docker containers` command as analogous to `docker images`?  This would help clear up the confusion some newbies have between `containers` and `images`.

Comment: A typo is still in the documentation a year later: `https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/step_four/` where it says: `FROM docker/whalesay:latest
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y fortunes
CMD /usr/games/fortune -a | cowsay`  That's why I ran into the above problem.